# Font-face ie8 issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I am using a custom font-family with following css rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'matrix';
    src: url('MaSGRgLn.eot');
    src: url('MaSGRgLn.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('MaSGRgLn.woff') format('woff'), url('MaSGRgLn.ttf') format('truetype'), url('MaSGRgLn.svg#MatrixScriptGr-RegularLin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have transformed my main font to all alternatives to be sure. Those work fine for all browsers except for ie < ie9. Is there sth i am missing or haven't paid attention to?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to note, based on my tests, is that the font-family name must match that what is inside the EOT file (viewable with hex-editor or if you have a matching TTF and Windows, the font preview will tell you).

IE8 does not display your font if the name differs, IE9 (even in IE8 mode) doesn't have this problem.

In your case, the SVG version has the name "MatrixScriptGr-RegularLin". Try using the same name in you CSS @font-face font-family definition.